# Most vs. Majority

Tags: meaning

Can these expressions be used interchangeably? Do they mean exactly the same or is there any subtle difference in meaning?

> Most cars run on gasoline.

> The majority of cars runs on gasoline.

> A majority of cars runs on gasoline.

Thank you.

Comment: **The majority**  and **A majority** both are different due to the articles before them.                     Most means **The majority of**

Comment: Thank you. What is the difference between "the majority of" and "a majority of"?

Comment: Similar question is available in this site, you can go through.

Comment: I cannot find it.

Comment: You can google "A majority of vs The majority of", you must find it.

Comment: https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/38244/what-is-the-difference-in-meaning-between-a-majority-of-and-the-majority-of

Comment: The answers in the link are hesitant, inconsistent and inconclusive. I don't know if I have to use **the majority of** or **a majority of**.

Comment: @pierrot5 part of the reason the answers are "hesitant, inconsistent and inconclusive" is that there really isn't much of a difference between "a majority" and "the majority." Technically they refer to slightly different things, but can pretty much always substitute for each other.

Answer (score 1):

In most contexts, both mean the same thing - more than half.

Traditionally, 'majority' is only used with countable nouns (cars, people etc), whereas you could use 'most' for non-countable nouns (eg "most of the water spilt").

However, like the historic difference between 'fewer' and 'less', the rules are not always strictly obeyed in everyday speech and even in less formal written English. In any case, 'majority' has always been used with percentages, so if you spilt more than 50% of some water you could rightly say the majority of it spilt.