# "the majority of" vs. "a majority of"

Tags: meaning

Is there any difference between these 2 sentences? Do they mean exactly the same?

> **The majority of** men **does** not have a moustache.

> **A majority of** men **do** not have a moustache.

I am using a singular verb in the first example, and a plural verb in the second example, because this seems to be the rule, though maybe it is a wrong rule:

https://www.grammarphobia.com/blog/2007/09/majority-rules.html

P.S. The question is derived from the below sources, which provide inconsistent, unclear, hesitant, inconclusive answers. Let us try to solve it once and for all!

[the majority of + plural noun + singular vs. plural verb](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/323976/the-majority-of-plural-noun-singular-vs-plural-verb)

[Most vs. Majority](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/323973/most-vs-majority)

[What is the difference in meaning between "A majority of" and "The majority of"?](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/38244/what-is-the-difference-in-meaning-between-a-majority-of-and-the-majority-of)

Comment: I find the version with the singular verb decidedly odd.

Comment: "I am using a singular verb in the first example, and a plural verb in the second example, because this seems to be the rule" <-- This is not a rule. In general, notional agreement has nothing to do with "a" vs. "the".

Comment: The majority of men **at my university**: specific. The other is general. It is always, always the same thing: the is specific, a is not.

Answer (score 0):

Whether it's "A majority" or "The majority" is irrelevant here. The determining factor is "**a** mustache".

A mustache cannot be shared, so the having must be related to the individual members of the majority.

The majority as a whole cannot have "a mustache".
Each individual does or does not have a mustache.

So "The" or "A" majority of men **do not** have **a** mustache.
Or "The" or "A" majority of men **do not** have mustache**s**.

One would use the singular only when talking about the majority itself rather than the members of that majority.
"A majority of men **has** been elected to the senate." (as compared with a majority of women).